# Uninitialized constant trying to reopen a Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using a plugin in Rails, and I call its methods without problems:

```
plugin_module::class_inside_module.method_a(...)
```

I want to re-open the **class_inside_module** and add a new method, I tried in many different ways. I can't figure out why in this way doesn't work:

```
class plugin_module::class_inside_module
  def new_method
    puts 'new method'
  end
end
```

I get the error: **uninitialized constant plugin_module**, but how is possible if I can call without problem **plugin_module::class_inside_module.any_methods** ?

Do you know why I get that error ? why "uninitialized constant" ? (it is a class declaration :-O )

Do you have any ideas how I can add a new methods in a class inside a module (that is part of a plugin) ?

Thank you,
Alessandro

Comment: I provided "fake code" to simplify the issue, it's not mandatory to supply real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have written your class and module-names like you did, so `plugin_module` instead of `PluginModule` this is against ruby/rails standards, and rails will not be able to automatically find the class and module.

If you write something like

```
module MyModule
  class MyClass

  end
end
```

Rails will expect this file to be located in `lib\my_module\my_class`.
But this can always easily be overwritten by explicitly doing a require.

So in your case, when you write

```
module plugin_module::class_inside_module
```

Rails will not know where to find the module `plugin_module`.
This way of writing only works if module `plugin_module` is previously defined (and loaded).

So either add the correct require, or rename your modules to standard rails naming, or write it as follows:

```
module plugin_module
  class class_inside_module
```

This way will also work, because now the order no longer matters. 
If the module is not known yet, this will define the module as well.
Either you are re-opening the class, or you define it first (and the actual definition will actually reopen it).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reopening the module that's wrapping the class, rather than relying on ::?

```
module plugin_module
  class class_inside_module
    def new_method
      puts 'new_method'
    end
  end
end
```

By the way, you know that the proper name for modules and classes is use CamelCase with a capital first letter?

```
module PluginModule
  class ClassInsideModule
    def new_method
      puts 'new_method'
    end
  end
end
```